# Delete Button with image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I implemented a demo using a GridView in DevExpress for MVC.

I want to set an image for Delete Button in my GridViewPartial View.

Someone knows how can I set it?

```
@{
var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings => {
...
settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
settings.CommandColumn.ShowNewButton = true;
settings.CommandColumn.ShowEditButton = true;
...
            });
    if (ViewData["EditError"] != null){
    grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
}
}

@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Thanks Mates.

EDITED:
Trying this

```
settings.SettingsCommandButton.DeleteButton.ButtonType = GridCommandButtonSettings.Image;
settings.SettingsCommandButton.DeleteButton.Image.Url = "~/content/images/icons/icon_delete.png";
```

It returns "Is needed a reference, method or property non statics "DevExpress.Web.GridCommandButtonSettings.Image.get""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight update for newer versions of DevExpress.  ButtonType has been [deprecated](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebGridViewCommandColumn_ButtonTypetopic) in favor of Render Mode.

**New**

```
settings.SettingsCommandButton.RenderMode = GridCommandButtonRenderMode.Image; 
settings.SettingsCommandButton.DeleteButton.Image.Url = "~/Content/Images/next.png";
```

**Obsolete**

```
settings.SettingsCommandButton.DeleteButton.ButtonType = GridCommandButtonRenderMode.Image;
```

Comment: Thanks for the review @PortageMonkey :):)

Answer (score 0):

Did it,

In Razor View (probably you are using GridViewPartial) define the button through:

```
settings.SettingsCommandButton.DeleteButton.ButtonType = GridCommandButtonRenderMode.Image;
settings.SettingsCommandButton.DeleteButton.Image.Url = "~/Content/Images/next.png";
```